# Analytic Solution for ODE

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I HAVE EQUATION

```
y - 7(e^x/x)dydx=0
```

How to find analytic solution in Mathematica?

My work :

1. I simplify the equations become y'=yx/7e^x
2. I run in Mathematica,

   ```
   DSolve[y'[x] == (y[x] x)/(7 e^x), y[x], x]
   ```

I get result:

```
{{y[x] -> E^(1/7 E^-x (-1 - x)) C[1]}}.
```

Questions:

- Are my simplifications correct?
- Do I type correct code in step 2?
- How to find exact value of C in the result, because I want to use to find y' for given x value

Thank you for the answer

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about math - **not** programming - and thus belongs on math.stackexchange.com

Comment: While this is sort of a programming question, I concur with @marc_s that this would be better suited to math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: You will have to specify initial conditions to get a specific value for `C[1]`. e.g. `DSolve[{y'[x] == (y[x] x)/(7 Exp[x]), y[0] == 1}, y[x], x]`. Check the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DSolveIntroduction.html).

Comment: Base on your suggestion, i do the same way to solve the equation y''+4y'+5y-60=0 (it is second order of dif. eqaution). I give the code in wolfram like this, DSolve[{y''[x] == (-4 y'[x] - 5 y[x] + 60), y[0] == 5} y[x], x], i give initial condition =5, and i GET NO RESULT. whats wrong with my code ?